# jQuery validate remote message

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I try to display an error message when email is used with jQuery validation.
Unfortunately there is no error message, when the email is already used.
I tried the following:

Javascript

```
$('#registerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        registerEmail: {
            required: true,
            remote: 'ajax/ajax.validateEmail.php'
        }
    },
    messages: {
        registerEmail: {
           remote: 'E-Mail already taken'
        }
    }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM members m WHERE mEmail = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['registerEmail']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();

if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    echo false;
}else{
    echo true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need echo return `true` or `false` in the backend php file.

Instead of

```
echo(json_encode(false));
```

change

```
echo 'false';
```

Same for `TRUE`

[Example](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-ajax-validation-remote-rule/)

**Explanation:**

jQuery remote method required an output either `true` or `false` from remote url.

If we echo true there, jQuery consider it as boolen `true`

and if we echo `false`, jQuery will convert it to boolean `false`.

Comment: Hey thanks. I did it without apostrophes (echo true;), cause with nothing happens. But now on every onBlur the email field gets red with a validation message '1' ?!

Answer (score 0):

And there is a syntax error:

```
$('#registerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        registerEmail: {
        required: true,
        remote: 'ajax/ajax.validateEmail.php'
    },
```

should

```
$('#registerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        registerEmail: {
            required: true,
            remote: 'ajax/ajax.validateEmail.php'
        }
    },
```

Comment: Sorry, was just a mistake in the pasting, not in the script ;)

Comment: Then the answer of @programming-student is good for you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, find the trick:

- Edited Javascript line to: `remote: { url: 'ajax/ajax.validateEmail.php', type:'post', async:false }`
- Removed: `header('Content-type: application/json');`
- Edited return line to: `echo json_encode( false );`

Hope this will help anyone too :)